# Spark timestamp difference

Tags: java, apache-spark, timestamp

I am trying to do a timestamp difference in Spark and it is not working as expected.

Below is how I'm trying to

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*
df = df.withColumn("TimeStampDiff", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.col("TimeStampHigh"), "HH:mm:ss").minus(unix_timestamp(df.col("TimeStampLow"), "HH:mm:ss")),"HH:mm:ss"))
```

Values

```
TimeStampHigh - 15:57:01
TimeStampLow - 00:11:57
```

It returns me a result of `10:45:04`
Expected output - `15:45:04`

My other alternative is to go to an UDF with Java implementation.

Any pointers will help.

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`from_unixtime`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_unixtime(ut:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (emphasis mine):

> Converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a string representing the timestamp of that moment **in the current system time zone** in the given format.

Clearly your system or JVM is not configured to use UTC time.

You should do one of the following:

- Configure JVM to use appropriate time zone (`-Duser.timezone=UTC` for both `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`).
- Set `spark.sql.session.timeZone` to use  appropriate time zone.

Example:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("15:57:01", "00:11:57")).toDF("TimeStampHigh", "TimeStampLow")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [TimeStampHigh: string, TimeStampLow: string]

scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "GMT-5")  // Equivalent to your current settings

scala> df.withColumn("TimeStampDiff", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.col("TimeStampHigh"), "HH:mm:ss").minus(unix_timestamp(df.col("TimeStampLow"), "HH:mm:ss")),"HH:mm:ss")).show
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|TimeStampHigh|TimeStampLow|TimeStampDiff|
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|     15:57:01|    00:11:57|     10:45:04|
+-------------+------------+-------------+


scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")  // With UTC

scala> df.withColumn("TimeStampDiff", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.col("TimeStampHigh"), "HH:mm:ss").minus(unix_timestamp(df.col("TimeStampLow"), "HH:mm:ss")),"HH:mm:ss")).show
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|TimeStampHigh|TimeStampLow|TimeStampDiff|
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|     15:57:01|    00:11:57|     15:45:04|
+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I tried setting spark configuration in spark job. The result stays same

Comment: Thanks user9613318. I shall set and check

Comment: I tried specifying in two ways and but it didnt respond

1. I tried setting in code when i create Spark conf 
         SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(sparkApplicationName);
        conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g");
        sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

2. I tried passing when i submit my spark job with
--conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=UTC

Is it something i miss out here @user9613318

Comment: If you use outdated Spark version, `‘spark.sql.session.timeZone` might not be supported